# Problem with basic Maths in Python and discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, math, discord.py

I'm pretty new to programming and i wanted to start programming with Python. After some testing i wanted to do a simple Python bot. Basically all i wanted it to do was to calculate simple Problems. For example "!calculate 22 * 2". My Problem is, that the operators -,* and / always return an error and + does the wrong thing. If the command is "!calculate 22 + 2" the output will be "222". I don't know hot to fix this.
I've already made a simple command-line calculator where almost the same script worked.
Sorry if my english is bad and thanks to anyone who tries to help.
Here's the part of the code with the calculator.

```
@bot.command(name="calculate", help="Calculates simple Maths")
async def roll(ctx, number1, operator, number2):


number1 = float(number1)
number2 = float(number2)

if operator == "+":
    result=number1 + number2
if operator == "-":
    result=number1 - number2
if operator == "*":
    result=number1 * number2
if operator == "/":
    result=number1 / number2
result=str(result)

await ctx.send("Your result is "+result+".")
```

I used the tutorial of [Real Python](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/)

[Discord Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiOGD.png)

[VSCode Output, Error of the first command.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBeq2.png)

Comment: The error-message makes clear that the type conversion to float did not take place. So "22" + "2" is "222" for strings and -*/ are not working for strings. so check via `type()` or `isinstance()`

Comment: `message.content` is a `str`, so the `+` operator concatenates the strings, and you get the merged string, which is what you should expect. Convert the content to `int` using `int(message.content`.

Comment: And yes, the problem is the wrong indentation. It works fine when I run it.

Comment: Note: The `if / if / if / if:` should really be replaced by `if / elif / elif / elif:` since only one alternative is possible.

Comment: Thanks. I actually got it working now thanks to those comments.

Comment: You could even use `ast.literal_eval` for math expressions - those are save and don't have any code exec problems.